# Disable webserver write access wordpress-Digital Ocean

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have used the following commands in Putty to ENABLE rewrite, so I can update wordpress in my LAMP stack Wordpress install.

```
$sudo a2enmod rewrite
$sudo chown -R www-data /var/www
```

I would like to disable rewrite so no one can install plugins and update wordpress automatically from wordpress admin area. What command should I use to do so?

Comment: `rewrite` in apache module does a different thing, it enables the dynamic-cutom url available at web server level, so no altering that. However, i think you may be looking to tighten your security by restricting file permissions. If we suppose achieve that, then you as an admin also won't be able to update plugin and wordpress _at ease_. Is that what you are looking to achieve here ?

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm trying to do